# Using Razor inside VueJs Component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, vue.js

To avoid repeat re-writing the same code multiple times,I'm using VueJs component feature to make a component that includes the Select dropdown list.
The code goes like this

```
 Vue.component('select-component', {
        template: `
            <label>elType</label>
            <div class="col-md-colwidth">
            <select>
                <option value=""></option>
                @foreach (elType s in ViewBag.elTypes)
                {
                    <option value="@s[elType+"ID"]">@s["Designation"+elType]</option>
                }
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" v-model="elTarget">
            </div>
            `,
        props: {
            elType: {
                type: String,
                default: 'User'
            },
            elTarget: {
                type: String,
                default: 'user'
            },
            colwidth: {
                type: int,
                default: '3'},


        }
    })
```

As you can see, I'm requiring some data list I brought from the ViewBag
but all i get is that the Razor is always ignoring that it is inside a Vue Component and giving "The type or namespace name 'elType' could not be found ".

P.S: 
1) the input Hidden is used in the original code to manipulate the bs jQuery select2

2)Don't mind the elTarget and elType :p it's actually same thing except I'm lazy to camelCase the word :p

3)I tried to wrap the  inside @{    } but still toggle the same error

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Razor 'inside' a Vue component because Razor generates the page server-side before Vue gets to do its stuff in the browser. What you have there is a Vue component inside a Razor page. elType is defined as a Vue prop, so it likely isn't in your view bag?

In any case, please don't do this! Use Razor ***or*** Vue. If you choose Vue, your vue components are static .js or .vue files, your data arrives via AJAX calls, and you loop through elTypes with `v-for`, in the browser. Any other way will lead to madness :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could send your razor with props to the component if necessary:

View file

```
<component-name :prop1="@Model.somethingOtherThanString" prop2="@Model.aString"></component-name>
```

Vue file

```
props: {
  prop1: Boolean,
  prop2: String
}
```